# How do I change how much disk space Ubuntu has?

Tags: 12.04, acer, ram

I installed ChruBuntu on my Chomebook Acer C7 about 2 weeks ago and I chose to allocate 10 gigs.  I didn't know that that would be my amount of disk space I would be allowed to use.  I want to install Adobe After Effects and It will not allow me due to the fact that I don't have enough disk space.  I do know I have plenty of disk space because I own a 320G hard drive.  Could someone please tell me how to change the amount of disk space I allocate for Ubuntu?  (It was the time where when installing Ubuntu it asked me how much space I wanted 1-299, and I chose 10)

Comment: Are you sure you can run Adobe After Effects on Linux?

Comment: Yes I am. I use Wine exe runner

Comment: But I don't have enough space

Comment: If you are only using 10 gigs of your 320 gig drive for Ubuntu then presumably you still have Windows installed as well?  Why not use After Effects in Windows?  Running it under Wine sounds like too many headaches to me, if it works at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. backup your data - probably the data in your /home/your_username folder
2. reinstall Ubuntu; partition your harddisk, choose a GUID-partition table

   - /dev/sda1: a primary partition of 20 G, with boot flag, ext4 filesystem, where you will mount the root (/) of the filesystem;
   - an extended partition of 300 Gbyte;
   - in that extended partition 3 logical partitions:
   - /dev/sda5: SWAP space, as big as your RAM, maximum 4 G, you probably don't need it, but it makes suspend to disk possible;
   - /dev/sda6: a partition where you will mount your /home directory, 150 G, ext4 filesystem:
   - /dev/sda7: a partition that you keep for the future, kind of free space, 146 G, ext4 or whatever, you will not use it for now

Make sure that 20G is enough for Ubuntu, Wine **and Adobe After Effects** - check.

Remember: partitioning is a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

You can resize your partition all you want, just make absolutely sure that your device is plugged in. If the device shuts down during the operation, it could damage the filesystem. I personally make sure I have a **full battery** and that the **device is plugged in**. This would save you having to reinstall and configure all over again.