# Ubuntu only lets me use 10GB of my 305GB hard drive

Tags: 12.04

I have a 305 gb hard drive but Ubuntu only lets me use 10 of it.  I don't know why but it does.  Can someone explain this to me like I'm a 12 year old please because I just tried to fix it with manual partition and I wiped my whole damn computer.

Comment: You've already asked this question before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/291225/how-do-i-change-how-much-disk-space-ubuntu-has

Comment: It sounds like you're having difficulty with Ubuntu and it's going to be a steep learning curve for you.  You already own a copy of Windows and a copy of Adobe After Effects - what are your reasons for wanting to switch?  If it's because you want to learn new things (which you will do a lot of) then that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I am about the farthest thing from an expert on this, however if you "wiped your whole damn computer", then why not download a new installation and start afresh? When installing, you have the option to allocate the desired amount of HDD space to the Ubuntu OS. If all your data is truly gone, or there was nothing of importance, then just reinstalling the OS should take care of your problem.

Comment: Yes but whenever I reinstall Ubuntu which I have done about 4 times now,  it doesnt ask me anymore

Comment: @user155791 From the livecd, see what GParted says - see why Ubuntu partition is only 10gb.